# Retrieving a generic type value from an object dictionary without exceptions

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, boxing

Is there a generic way (preferably with an extension method) that you can retrieve values (could be decimal, short, int or string) casted to the right type from a `Dictionary<string, object>` without it failing when the key does not exist?

Comment: Yes, there is...you just need to write it.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful contribution

Comment: Maybe I've been pretty ironic but meaning was: first try by yourself, you should first try to solve the problem and then ask on SO when you fail. In this question I just see a requirement, not an attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key)
    {
        object value = null;
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(key);
        }

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

**edit:** If you don't want it to throw anything, just remove the line that throws a new KeyNotFoundException. I find it handy to have that, because KeyNotFoundException never includes the friggin name of the column not found. This way, the error message will BE the column name :-)

Comment: Why not just use `Convert.ChangeType()`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: THis will throw when the key does not exist, also why all the `ConvertTo...` calls. If the value is a T then a cast will suffice.

Comment: As the method `Convert.ChangeType()` returns an `object`, can just use it like this: return `(T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));`